# Does anybody load sos.dll in vc++ 2008?

Tags: visual-c++

Does anybody know how to load sos.dll in vc++ 2008?
I tried to run the following command and get an error:

.load

Error during command: extension could not be found

.load sos.dll

Error during command: extension could not be found

Comment: I solved the problem by adding path to the dll

Comment: How to set a path so I don't need give a path each time

Comment: Try add path of this dll to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you solved this? Do you mean you added the full path to the sos.dll?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. That worked for me too. Command I used was: `.load "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll"`

Comment: @Southsouth: If you solved it, then write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer from comment:

> I solved the problem by adding path to the dll

-

> nevermind, I figured it out. That worked for me too. Command I used
>   was: .load "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll"